# error in sql update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I upgrade the salaries of the operators who attended claims in 2012 by 11%,
try

```
update operator or
September o.sueldo = o.sueldo + (o.sueldo * 0.11)
where exists (select 1 from claim where r.cod_operador r = o.cod_operador
and r.fecha Between '2012-01-01 'and '2012-12-31');
```

but it says
"Error Code: 1241. Operand Should Contain 1 column (s)" 
anyone know how I can fix these errors?

sqlfiddele here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2771

Comment: `o.sueldo + (o.sueldo * 0.11)` might be expressed as `o.sueldo * 1.11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you do to this statement??

This way it at least fits your tables:

```
update operador o
set o.sueldo = o.sueldo + (o.sueldo * 0.11)
where exists (select 1 from reclamo r where r.cod_operador = o.cod_operador
and r.fecha Between '2012-01-01 'and '2012-12-31');
```

But I don't know if it will do the right thing in the end ...

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should be

```
update operator o
SET o.sueldo = o.sueldo + (o.sueldo * 0.11)
where exists (select 1 from claim where r.cod_operador r = o.cod_operador
and r.fecha Between '2012-01-01 'and '2012-12-31');
```